# Weird behaviour in PHP and Apache2: different output in different servers

Tags: php, apache, mamp, lamp

I'm experiencing different outputs in PHP code running in Mac and Linux.

I have 2 servers running the following code:

```
    $ltt = ((ord($str[7]) << 24) | (ord($str[8]) << 16) | (ord($str[9]) << 8) | (ord($str[10]))) / 1000000;
```

Even the `ord(str[ ])` outputs are the same:

```
[7] = 254
[8] = 26
[9] = 22 
[10] = 216
```

But, on the MAMP stack (Mac) running php 5.3.6, if $ltt is originally supposed to be a negative number, it returns `4263.12265` (incorrect).

On the LAMP stack (Ubuntu) running same php version, it will return the exact negative value `-31.84465`.

This happens only with negative numbers..

**Update Addl. Info:**

- A var dump gives `þØçï_Kstring(25) "þØçï_K"`
- bin2hex gives `000e1b00000000fe1a16d806e707ef0000045f0000004b0000`

Simplying the function to include only numeric inputs, the output **still differs**:

```
$ltt = (254 << 24 | 26 << 16 |  22 << 8 | 216)/ 1000000;
```

`4263.12265` on MAMP and `-31.84465` on LAMP

Comment: Are the php configurations the same on both machines? The same version does not always mean the same setup ;)

Comment: Is one 64-bit and the other 32?  I don't think it actually *should* matter here though...

Comment: Both are 32 bit, and configs are stock, except for some changes in memory limit and post_Data..

Comment: Your code's output depends on its input and we don't have it. I suggests you provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) we can play with. Additionally, remove components from your expression until you find which fragment causes the difference. Last but not least, use [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) and [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex) to inspect variables rather than plain echos.

Comment: I believe it should be `115.804143` and your expected output is wrong.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario thanks for replying.
- A var dump gives `þØçï_Kstring(25) "þØçï_K"`
- bin2hex gives `000e1b00000000fe1a16d806e707ef0000045f0000004b0000`

Comment: @SalmanA: sorry, had posted another output. Please check again.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: have updated the post with the dumps.

Comment: You've hard-coded the values (which is great for us to test) but you haven't tried simplifying the expression...

Comment: `06e707ef` begins at offset 11, not 7.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: This is stock code for a function I don't entirely understand as I'm just learning PHP.. So I'm unable to simplify further.. sorry!

Comment: What does `echo PHP_INT_SIZE` give you? This will help eliminate 32 vs 64 issue.

Comment: @SalmanA I get '8' on the MAMP stack

Comment: Bingo. See @DaveRandom answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a 32 vs 64 bit problem.

Because your most significant byte is > 127, on a 32 bit platform this is interpreted as a negative value because of integer overflow - the most significant bit is set. On a 64-bit platform it is not.

The solution is to use `pack()` and `unpack()` so you can specify that the integer should be signed. **EDIT** <strike>Fixed this code sample</strike> See edit 2

```
$packed = pack('C*', ord($str[7]), ord($str[8]), ord($str[9]), ord($str[10]));
$unpacked = unpack('l', $packed);
$lat = current($unpacked);
```

...however you should also be conscious that this will not work on a little-endian architecture, because the byte ordering will be wrong. You can simply reverse the order of the packed bytes to work around this, but I am just trying to wrap my head around a works-everywhere solution.

**EDIT 2**

OK, it took me a while to wrap my head around this but we got there in the end:

What you need to do is, if the most significant bit is set, OR the result with a number where the least significant 32 bits are not set but the rest are. So the following works on both 32 and 64 bit:

```
<?php

// The input bytes as ints
$bytes = array(254, 26, 22, 216);

// The operand to OR with at the end
$op = $bytes[0] & 0x80 ? (~0 << 16) << 16 : 0;

// Do the bitwise thang
$lat = (($bytes[0] << 24) | ($bytes[1] << 16) | ($bytes[2] << 8) | $bytes[3]) | $op;

// Convert to float for latitude
$lat /= 1000000;

echo $lat;
```

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I only know this with certainty because I did the math on the example bytes and it works out. The MAMP stack is 64 bit. However, my proposed solution code is wrong :-( working on it now, but if you have a solution I'd be happy to upvote it because it's still very early and my mental binary calculator is not yet working properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I'm still getting 0 as output.

Comment: @Reddox The 32/64 bit problem is definite, my solution is wrong. I'm working on it now, I may need some tea first so if someone gets there before me you should probably accept that instead.

Comment: This works great if the inputs are as specified in the question.. if the input $bytes is intended to be positive `$bytes = array(6,231,7,239);
`, however, I get an incorrect `-4179.1631536` instead of `115`. Should I just check if I'm getting a negative output before performing this?

Comment: @Reddox Damn it! I hoped I could fix that before you read this, 1 second.

Comment: @Reddox See edit above. There's actually no need to check the platform int size, only to check whether the most significant bit is set.

Comment: FYI the double `<< 16` is because PHP throws up if you try and `<< 32` on a 32 bit platform, something that annoys me a great deal on a regular basis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. any tutorials for a Php novice on bytes and other aspects we saw in this question..?

Comment: @Reddox The important thing to note there is that this is not PHP specific. Bitwise operation work the same everywhere, and the syntax for them in most C-like languages is the same. I don't have a specific tutorial I can point you at (although Googling "bitwise tutorial" yields plenty of reasonable looking results ;-) ) but I have always found the best way to learn is by doing - I really got to grips with this by implementing a DHCP server in PHP, DNS is also another good protocol to choose for this. If you are not as much of a sad-act as me you may find this a bit heavy though.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Appreciate the help!